# Calculate: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{q^n+n}-\sqrt{n}$ with $q > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

I tried to do this task by myself, but am not able to solve it.

This is what I have so far:
\begin{align*}
        &\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{q^n+n}-\sqrt n \\
        =&\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{q^n+n}-\sqrt{n})\frac{\sqrt{q^n+n}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{q^n+n}+\sqrt{n}}\\
        =&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{q^n+n-n}{\sqrt{q^n+n}+\sqrt{n}}\\
        =&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{q^n}{\sqrt{q^n+n}+\sqrt{n}}\\
        =&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{q^n+n}}{q^n}+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{q^n}}\\
        =&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{(q^n+n)^\frac{1}{2}}{((q^n)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}+\frac{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}{((q^n)^2)^\frac{1}{2}}}\\
        =&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{q^n+n}{q^{2n}}}+\sqrt{\frac{n}{q^{2n}}}}
    \end{align*}

Edit: I understand that for $q \le 1$, the sequence converges, and for $q > 1$, it diverges, but I would like a clear path to the solution. How does on prove that $\sqrt{q^n+n}-\sqrt{n}$ diverges when $q > 1$?

Comment: HINT.- We have $\sqrt{q^n+n}-\sqrt{n}=\dfrac{q^n}{\sqrt{q^n+n}+\sqrt{n}}=\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{\sqrt{q^n+n}+\sqrt{n}}{q^n}}$ whose limit is $\infty$ when $q\gt1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $0<q\le1$, then

$$0\le\sqrt{q^n+n}-\sqrt n\le\sqrt{1+n}-\sqrt n=\frac1{\sqrt{1+n}+\sqrt n}$$
By Squeeze Theorem, the limit is zero.

---

If $q>1$, we can find $N$ such that $q^n\ge n$ for $n\ge N$, then we have

$$\sqrt{q^n+n}-\sqrt n\ge\sqrt{n+n}-\sqrt n=(\sqrt2-1)\sqrt n\to\infty$$

Comment: Could you write a proof for the divergence?

Comment: yes, added @Snek

Comment: Thank you @MathFail